# Best Way to achieve conditional mysql where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Helllo folks,

I have one table with entries, those entries have a field *confidentiality* (Public, Confidential) and a field *type* (project, poster, publication, ...). 
So what do i want to do: I want to filter within my SELECT all entries but not the entries with a specified type and confidentiality.

E.g.:

```
type=project, confidentiality=public       | should be selected
type=project, confidentiality=confidential | should be not selected
type=poster, confidentiality=public        | should be selected
type=poster, confidentiality=confidential  | should be selected
```

Is there a good way to do this?

```
SELECT ...
WHERE (type = 'project' AND confidentiality = 'public') OR type = 'publication' OR type
= 'poster' OR type = 'lecture' OR type = 'committee'
GROUP BY
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, just replace your group of [`OR (...)`] statements with single 
`OR ... IN ('publication', 'poster', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, you want to select the records where `confidentiality` is not *confidential*. Right? Try this,

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
WHERE type <> 'project' AND confidentiality <> 'confidential'
```

OR is the same as

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
WHERE NOT (type = 'project' AND confidentiality = 'confidential')
```

Comment: I want all entries, but no projects that are confidential, but projects that are public. So the confidentiality for the other types doesn't matter.

Comment: so you only need this `confidentiality <> 'confidential'` and no other condition right? @MichaelEbert

Comment: but the other entries types that are confidential should be also selected

Comment: did you even try the query above? your point is not to select confidential projects. Isn't it @MichaelEbert?

Comment: try `WHERE NOT (type = 'project' AND confidentiality = 'confidential')`

Comment: I had some trouble and had to update a few DAOs in order to test, so took me a little bit.

Comment: Works fine, I also added support for multiple types filtering, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks OK, given the informations you gave.

Would this shorter query work?

```
SELECT ...
WHERE (type = 'project' AND confidentiality = 'public')
OR type <> 'project'
```

Note: the above query can be shortened as:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE confidentiality = 'public'
OR type <> 'project'
```

Comment: Looks also promising and shorter than the IN(...)

Comment: Yep :) Boolean algebra can help you a lot in programming! See here for an introduction to this subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Answer (score 0):

Your intended logic seems to be:

```
SELECT ... WHERE type != 'project' OR confidentiality = 'public';
```